# WCF Ria DomainService - Initialize WebService on StartUp

Tags: wcf, ria, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

Currently, my DomainService does perform an Initialization of a resource everytime a client is connecting to him. Every client should access the same instance of this resource.
I would like to initialize this resource on the StartUp of the WebService. Is there any chance to do that with WCF Ria Services?

**EDIT:**
Okay, don't mention it. I wanted to use this for an global DbContext object. This isn't a good idea anyway, because there will be multiple threads managed by the HttpApplication which would access the DbContext simultaneously. I will change my implementation to an "per Thread", respectively "per HttpContext", approach. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a class that contains a static property for that resource. In the DomainService you can then access that property. It would then be initialized only when it is accessed the first time.

Example:

```
public class ResManager {
    public static MyObject {...}
}
```

In the DomainService:

```
public IQueryable<SomeClass> GetSomeObjects()
{
    // you can access it here and it will not be initialized 
    // every time the DomainService is called
    MyObject obj = ResManager.MyObject;
    return new List<SomeClass>().AsQueryable();
}
```

If you want to initialize it when the Service is started, then you should be able to do that in the `Global` class.

Comment: I tried this with a static DbContext object. Now I'm getting the load error: "DbContext has been disposed". I've checked the calls to the DbContext constructor and destructor. The last one isn't called before the application shuts down. What's going on here?